# How to create a unique new file

Tags: java, file

I´m running a test getting some information from the web, and I send it to excel file.

But everytime that I run my test, it overwrites the previous file.

Is there anyway to create a new file and not overwrite the other one with another name?

If possible, can the name of the file be something that I want with the date that i ran the test?

This is the part that I create the excel file:

```
public void xlWrite(String strXLWrite) {
    try{
        FileOutputStream outTestDataStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/P_701362/Desktop/resultadoSiconv.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook xlWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet mySheet = xlWorkBook.createSheet("Sheet1");
            for (int i = 0; i < xlRows; i++) {
                HSSFRow row = mySheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    HSSFCell cells = row.createCell(j);
                    cells.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(localArray[i][j]));
                }
            }
            xlWorkBook.write(outTestDataStream);         
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to read and write data in same excel?

Comment: @HelpingHands no. read from one and write in another one.

Comment: Can you please put your whole code in question?

Comment: @HelpingHands Vivek Singh got the ideia. I know how to write in another file. I just want to create another excel file with another name and if possible with the current date. And not overwriting the previous file.

Comment: But that is simple. I assume you are using FileInputputStream to get data from excel and FileOutputStream to write data in excel. so of course FileOutputStream will create new excel with new name.

Comment: @HelpingHands yes I know. but I want to create new excel with the current date on the name. Got it?

Comment: then you can pass that name in excel path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
FileOutputStream outTestDataStream = new FileOutputStream(
   "C:/Users/P_701362/Desktop/" + time + ".xls");
```

**EDIT:**

```
String strTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss")
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis());
FileOutputStream outTestDataStream = new FileOutputStream(
       "C:/Users/P_701362/Desktop/" + strTime + ".xls");
```

Comment: it will create a file with current timestamp for you.

Comment: I think this gives a random number "1418301531535". I don´t get it. @VivekSingh

Comment: This gives me in milliseconds. I want in this format: dd/MM/yyyy. @vivek

Comment: And whoever voted this answer down actually this is what he was looking for... :D